# Can I Use Google Input tools to type Malayalam language?

Tags: input-language

I would like to install Google input tools in Ubuntu. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by doing the following:

- Open the terminal by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
- Install `ibus` by running: `sudo apt-get install ibus`.
- Install the library for Indian regional languages by running: `sudo apt install ibus-m17n m17n-contrib`.
- Now add `ibus` to your startup applications:

  1. Open Startup Applications from the dash.
  2. Click on <kbd>Add</kbd>.
  3. Enter the name as "ibus".
  4. In the command box type: "ibus-daemon".
  5. Save.
- Log out and log in back.
- Go to `System > Preferences > Ibus preferences`.
- Select the "`input method`" tab.
- From the drop-down menu, Select an input method: `Malayalam > Swanalekha`.
- Click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button.
- Open a text editor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to change the language.

That should help you! Please, leave some feedback when it does.